# iOS, SQLite: Method doesn't insert a parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, methods

Some strange issue:

```
-(void)registerNewItemStatus:(int)itemID typeID:(int)typeID dated:(NSString*)date
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:user_data];
sqlite3* database = NULL;
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"DBAcc itemID: %d",itemID); // shows 9, so not null
    const char *sqlItems=sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO itemStatus(refID,kmID,enabled,grade,dated,memo)\
                                         VALUES(?,?,1,0,?,NULL)",itemID,typeID,date);
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlItems, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)

        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, itemID);
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 2, typeID);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [date UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    char* errmsg;
    sqlite3_exec(database, "sqlItems", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
    sqlite3_free((char*)errmsg);
    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement))
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_free((char*)sqlItems);
    sqlite3_close(database);

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"%s: prepare failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
}
```

My problem is that itemID do not get inserted in db. shows null. Where's the evil? You help is much appreciated.

Comment: `sqlite3_bind_int()` has a return value - check it! It may indicate a range error or something else.

Comment: Not the case. typeID is similar thing as itemID. typeID gets inserted ok and only itemID not.

Comment: The problem isn't obvious from this bit of code. Can you post your database schema? In particular the column types of the table you are inserting into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code were indented properly, you would see this:

```c
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlItems, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, itemID);
sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 2, typeID);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [date UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

You have to add proper error handling.

Please note that `sqlite3_finalize` must *always* be called, even when `sqlite3_step` fails.